# SVN Export & Import from Local Copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, bitnami

I had an svn server which is not working now. I have the latest revision of svn on my local computer (Windows-Tortoise SVN). I set up new svn server (bitnami-subversion) and now I want to import my local copy to new server. Can I import my local copy with keeping revision history?

Answer (score 0):

No. WC have not any history changes, only *some state of codebase*